# How can I do a for example a image link to change the website content from one language to another?

Tags: wordpress

I have made a website in html/css which I then used in a blank theme in wordpress since the one I'm doing ti for wanted an easy way to edit the content later. In html/css I could just use a image link to send the user to another .html-doc and problem solved, can I do this similar in wordpress? If I add more pages, the more menu-items I get now which is not what I want.

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Sorry, didnt realize it existed... I take my business there and post the answer here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try the easy way and install a plugins for bilingual website such as qtranslate. 
That will do everything for you, you hust need to fill out your post with the language you wish to have.